# API to get list of files uploaded to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is there an API to get a list of files currently uploaded to Firebase Hosting? Note that I am not talking about Firebase Storage here but Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [ListFiles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions.files/list) endpoint will list files for a specified version. Versions can be found through the [ListReleases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.releases/list) endpoint.

Comment: Thanks mate! Exactly what I needed!